# indexedDb no events fire on open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, dom-events, indexeddb

I am seeing that sometimes neither of the events are being fired when doing `indexedDb.open()`.
If I set a timeout and observe the state of `openRequest`, the ready state is set = 'done'. If I do any transaction on the db in the `openRequest.result`, it works fine.

My guess is that in some cases the `openRequest` execution is complete before we get to attach `onsuccess` or other event handlers, in other words it does not get executed in the next event loop.

So, I can inspect the state after an 'x' amount of time if no event is fired. However this approach is hackish and fragile.
Does anyone know of a better way to address this?

```
 var db;
 var openRequest = window.indexedDB.open("todos", 1);
 openRequest.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error('error in open', event);
 };
 openRequest.onsuccess = (event) => { 
     console.log('success ' , event)
 };
 openRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event) => { 
     console.log('upgradeneeded ' , event);
     db = event.target.result;
     db.createObjectStore("toDoList", { keyPath: "taskTitle" }); 
 };
 openRequest.onblocked = (event) => { 
     console.log('blocked ' , event);
 }; 
 
 setTimeout( () => {
        console.log('timeout');
        console.log(openRequest.readyState) // equals done
 }, 10000)
```

Comment: Why are you using a global db variable? And, why are you only assigning a value to db from within the onupgradeneeded function?

Comment: this code is simplified with just logging statements. db will be set from success handler as well.

Comment: I had the same problem. No event listeners firing and I couldn't select the database in inspect tool to delete it. Had to clear "Cookies and  other site data" to get rid of it and it started working after. Chrome version: 105.0.5195.127

Answer (score 1):

Either a `"success"` or an `"error"` event must fire when `readyState` becomes `"done"`. If that's not happening then you've found a browser bug.

As noted in a comment, you'll want `db = event.target.result` in the `onsuccess` handler as well, otherwise `db` will not be set if an upgrade was not necessary. Are you certain that this isn't the source of your error? (i.e. maybe `success` *was* firing, you just weren't capturing the result?)

> in some cases the openRequest execution is complete before we get to attach 'onsuccess' or other event handlers

If that happened it would be a browser bug. Are you seeing consistent behavior across browsers? Can you reliable reproduce this?

Comment: I am seeing this behavior in the field, on chrome, edge, safari and firefox.   unfortunately  dont have a repro step.

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is not expected. It's likely there is a bug in your code; without seeing your actual code it's going to be difficult to make further suggestions.